# 'globalThis is not defined' in WebView 61 version on Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, android-webview

I tested my website made with React on the Emulator with Webview version 61.

with 95, 97 versions, it has no problem. But with version 61 it causes `Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined` and I figured it out that globalThis is supported from version 71. So, How can I handle this problem? Is there any alternatives for globalThis or is there any way to enable it? or change the version?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but with Brave browser. The web app created in React opens in most browsers such as Chrome, but on some like Safari or Brave it gives that error. Still no solution but if I find I will post here.